# Oauth with Box SDK (C# MVC .NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, sdk, box

I am currently trying to build a login for an MVC web app, using the Box SDK for .NET.
I cannot for the life of me wrap my head around the Oauth login process though.  I feel like I have it down close, but the actual POST action is confusing me.

Here is the process I am trying to follow:
https://developers.box.com/oauth/
I'm getting stuck on the "The First Leg" part.

I pass in my uri and data attributes to post as intended

```
var data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("response_type", "code"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", client_id),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("box_login", account_email)
        };

        HttpResponseMessage values = await Post("https://app.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize", data);
```

With the custom Post() method wrapper:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(string uri, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pairs)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
            var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
            return response;
        }

    }
```

But the "values" contents come back with the html for the Box authorization page.  Assumedly I'm supposed to redirect to this page... I just don't really know the best approach to do so (and then return).

I feel like this all probably boils down to my misunderstanding of how a POST works.  What obvious and simple thing am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

OAuth means external authentication. You have to redirect the user to the Box OAuth page rather then sending a Post request. The redirect URL in your app will decide where the authorization token is sent back and then you can get that authorization code and exchange it with access and refresh token using the Box .NET SDK or using a custom request.

The first phase of OAuth is not a part of SDK.